# How to implement a custom method as User.Identity.GetLastUserToken() to get last assigned token in two-factor authentication?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity, two-factor-authentication

I implement two-factor authetentication as seen in http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2014/02/18/adding-two-factor-authentication-to-an-application-using-asp-net-identity.aspx but I would like show to user in templete view a `TokenViewModel object` with two property, `TokenDate` and `TokenString` retrived by `@User.Identity.GetLastUserToken().TokenDate` and `@User.Identity.GetLastUserToken().TokenString` at View.

I just do it.

```
public static class ApplicationIdentityExtensions
{
    public static string FindFirstValue(this ClaimsIdentity identity, string claimType)
    {
        return null;
    }

    public static TokenViewModel GetLastUserToken(this IIdentity identity)
    {
        return new TokenViewModel(){ TokenDate = DateTime.Now, TokenString= "Token from Mock" };
    }

}
```

As you can see, `EmailTokenProvider` in `manager.RegisterTwoFactorProvider("EmailCode", new EmailTokenProvider<ApplicationUser>()` line was inherit by `IUserTokenProvider<TKey, TValue>` and them I implement by my self at my project.

This inherit must to implement those method:

```
    public Task<bool> ValidateAsync(string purpose, string token, UserManager<Usuario, int> manager, Usuario user)
    {
        //TODO: I guess, must to validate user custom token here using my _respositoryToken.
```

**I would like set token var in User.Identity scope but I don't know exactly.**

```
        return Task.FromResult(true);
    }
```

**How can I do that?**

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution here http://kevin-junghans.blogspot.co.uk/2013/12/using-claims-in-aspnet-identity.html

Just implement these code below:

```
var prinicpal = (ClaimsPrincipal)Thread.CurrentPrincipal;
var lasttoken = prinicpal.Claims.Where(c => c.Type == ClaimTypes.UserData).Select(c => c.Value).SingleOrDefault();
```

See:

```
public static TokenViewModel GetLastUserToken(this IIdentity identity)
{
    var prinicpal = (ClaimsPrincipal)Thread.CurrentPrincipal;
    return prinicpal.Claims.Where(c => c.Type == ClaimTypes.UserData).Select(c => c.Value).Select(i => new TokenViewModel{ TokenValue = i }).SingleOrDefault();
}
```